# What could be blocking my ports other than iptables and ufw?

Tags: firewall

I have disabled ufw and iptables is not present in my 18.04 Ubuntu but I can't anyone to connect to my applications in any port that I boot them.

I also have docker installed with many containers running but I have also tried disabling docker with no luck.

Comment: Can they ping you? Is there a firewall between your server and the clients?

Comment: `ufw` is a frontend for iptables but if `sudo ufw status` returns "inactive" then it should be disabled. Find out the local IP for your computer and then run the `nmap` command to check what ports are open and available. For example, if your local IP is 192.168.1.8: `nmap 192.168.1.8`

Comment: Give us a specific example. Also do `sudo iptables -v -x -n -L` . Edit your question adding this information.